# Is there any way to read cookie from different domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have two websites and both are in different domains. I want to read a cookie in web-2 which I am setting in web-1. Both the applications are written in ROR and open to code-change. This is basically required to identify a user landing to web-2 so as to know if he comes via web-1 or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share a cookie between two websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370495/share-a-cookie-between-two-websites)

Answer (score 0):

No. Web-1 can't read a cookie from web-2. 
For more information refer, [Share a cookie between two websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370495/share-a-cookie-between-two-websites)

Comment: @DeepankarSingh Please read the shared StackOverflow link. No other ways are available.