# Share cookies among domains in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I am working on a project in which i want to share the cookies among domains. I have successfully shared the cookies among subdomains but now i also want to share it on domain level. Can anyone please help me how can i achieve this.

For subdomain i did the following thing.

In app/config/session.php i changed the domain value to following.

```
'domain' => '.abc.com'
```

Then for setting cookie

```
 Cookie::queue('email', "test@test.com", 999999, null, '.abc.com');
```

This sets cookie for **one.abc.com** and **second.abc.com**. Now i want to achieve same functionality but for **abcd.com** and **xyz.com**.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370495/share-a-cookie-between-two-websites

Comment: @dhavalChheda thanks but some how i have to achieve this functionality.

Comment: You could use a web-service to send this data (if you can link users between domains -  if you know the id of a given user on both domains)