# How to preserve a cookie between frames in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, session-cookies

I use **electron 0.36.0** and I have a **cookie** for a page and this page has a **nested frame** with a different domain.

I need to somehow keep a cookie alive when going to this frame directly (different domain) and ideally, I want to avoid upgrades of electron (otherwise I would have to rewrite my code).

What's an ideal solution for my situation (it can be also a small workaround)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can now be shared with different domains so you will have to find a different way of doing what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain cookies alcuadrado has described a work around to do this in his post like below:

1. centralize all cookies in a single domain, let's say cookiemaker.com
2. when the user makes a request to example.com you redirect him to cookiemaker.com
3. cookiemaker.com redirects him back to example.com with the information you need

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370495/share-a-cookie-between-two-websites).