# php session_set_cookie_params() for two domains

Tags: php

I need to set the PHPSESSID coockie for just two domains:

- `www.domain.tld`
- `sub.domain.tld`.

Other subdomains should not share the same PHPSESSID.

I can use [session_set_cookies_param()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php), but as far as I can see, this can only set it for one domain or all subdomains.

But in my case, subdomain `anothersub.domain.tld` should not have this PHPSESSID.

I want this because we have images on a subdomain, and setting the PHPSESSID for all subdomains causes the browser to send the PHPSESSID cookie with the request. This has slight performance issues for static resources and it is recommended to use cookieless domains

Comment: This can't be done this way, this is unrelated to PHP. Use different domain for image hosting.

Comment: its not possible directly!
take a look at answered duplicate @ [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370495/share-a-cookie-between-two-websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370495/share-a-cookie-between-two-websites)

Comment: @emix, I thought so, then I need to register a new domain (different tld) for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done this way, this is unrelated to PHP. This is how cookies works in general. Only one domain (or a domain with a dot in front) can be set.

You have to use different domain for image hosting.

Answer (score 0):

While as was already explained, this is not technically possible, due to the cookie “syntax”, I think you should be able to work around that, if you simply set a second cookie yourself.

- Use `session_set_cookies_param` to have it set the cookie for `www.domain.tld` only.
- Add your own code after `session_start`, that sets the “same” cookie again, just for `sub.domain.tld` this time.

`session_name` and `session_id` help your figure out the necessary name and value; if you want, you can also use `session_get_cookie_params` to match other parameters (like lifetime and maybe path, if the latter makes any sense in the given setup) as well if you like.

---

Edit: Keep in mind though, that if the session id might change at any other point within your app after `session_start`, for example if `session_regenerate_id` is used anywhere, you will of course have to update your second cookie there as well.