# Is it possible to pass a cookie from one domain to another domain using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cookie generated from one domain as below using jquery post?

```
  $.ajax({
        url: _domainURL1 + '/domain1/auth/start',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        data: $('#data').val(),
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        complete: getCookie
    });


    function getCookie() {
         if (document.cookie) {
                $('#cookie').val(document.cookie);
            }
    }
```

Is it possible to attach the #cookie generated above from domain1 in the below request?

```
var data = {
                Type: "test1",
                ID: "testid1"
            };

         $.post(_domainURL2 + '/domain2/senddata', data, function (result) {
                alert("complete");
            });
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what is being asked. How is the cookie supposed to be used in the second request? And is this in the same top level document?

Comment: seems possible if CORS is enabled on second domain

Comment: If it is possible, do you have an example of how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: It's not possible, please go through the below link.
[Share-a-cookie-between-two-websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370495/share-a-cookie-between-two-websites)