# I am unable to authenticate outside the cloud run domain (*.run.app)

Tags: laravel, authentication, session

I have the following scenario and I am unable to authenticate outside the cloud run domain (run.app).

## Scenario

I have a Laravel application running on Cloud Run at the following address: https://devel-alberanexyz.a.run.app/

And I have a custom domain for this application, for example:
https://devel.alberane.com

Laravel is configured for "file" type sessions. I also tested with sessions of type "database".

My user database is accessible and I am logging in with the correct username and password.

## Here's the problem

I can authenticate on localhost and on Google's *.run.app domain.

I can't log in to my custom domain dev.alberane.com.

## Which I already tried.

- configure the SESSION DOMAIN
- Use SESSION "file" and "database"
- The "@csrf" entry is correct in the login form

## My question is:

How can I authenticate my application outside the *.run.app domain? Is there any extra configuration needed on my custom domain since I just included the CNAME directives in the DNS server?

tks

Comment: I don't believe this is typically done out of the box with laravel. I believe what you are attempting poses security risks from the applications perspective. I think a combination that laravel scopes cookies to the subdomain and not across multiple domains. Therefore I think, it would view what you are doing as CSRF threat and hence not support it. You need most likely handle the csrf_token and ensure it being passed along with the user and embedded correctly into the page. Also you will need to to check if that user is logged in and recreate the session with user id once they have moved.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer!

At this point I don't want to use any Google Cloud API, I'm just authenticating within my application for my users.

In the domain "*.run.app" everything works correctly, but when I change to any other domain, for example "dev.myapp.com" the authentication does not work. Even if I have this domain correctly configured in my .env (in the file or in the environment variables in cloud run).

I don't think it's a risk. Apparently, I have the correct configuration of my application. My question is much more about ClourRun and DNS

Comment: I dont think its cloud run, tbh. I dont think you can share cookies like that across domains.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370495/share-a-cookie-between-two-websites